# Server side paging and grouping of large dataset

Tags: mongodb, database-design, transformation

I'll try to explain the issue as best I can. Implement a grid with server paging. On request for N entities, DB should return a set of data which should be grouped or better said transformed in such a way that when the transformation phase is done it should result in those N entities.

Best way as I can see is something like this:

```
Query_all_data() => Result; (10000000 documents)
Transform(Result) => Transformed (100 groups)
Transformed.Skip(N).Take(N)
```

Transformation phase should be something like this:

```
Result = [d0, d1, d2..., dN]
Transformed = [
    { info: "foo", docs: [d0. d2, d21, d67, d100042] },
    { info: "bar", docs: [d3. d28, d121, d6271, d100042] },
    { info: "baz", docs: [d41. d26, d221, d567, d100043] },
    { info: "waz", docs: [d22. d24, d241, d167, d1000324] }
]
```

Every object in Transformed is an entity in grid.

I'm not sure if it's important but the DB in question is MongoDB and all documents are stored in one collection. Now, the huge pitfall of this approach is that it's way to slow on large dataset which will most certainly be the case.

Is there a better approach. Maybe different DB design?

Answer (score 1):

@dakt, you can store your data in couple of different ways based on how you are going to use the data. In the process it may also be useful to store data in de-normalized form where in some duplication of data may occur.

1. Store data as individual documents as mentioned in your problem statement
2. Store the data in transformed format in your problem statement. It looks like you have a consistent way of mapping the docs to some tag. If so, why not maintain documents such that they are always embedded for those tags. This certainly has limitation on number of docs that you may be able to contain base on the 16MB document limit.

I would suggest looking at the MongoDB use-cases - http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/ and see if any of those are similar to what you are trying to achieve.